# Objective C errors in my code

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have created this in a terminal application in Xcode but usure how to remedy the errors.
Sorry I'm a total beginner.
There errors are at

```
void addToTotal (float cost, int quantity)
```

Would someone be able to help me with my code?

```
//
//  main.m
//  ShoppingList


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>  //? not sure if this is correct 

//Gobal variables visable from any function

//------VARIABLES
int totalItems = 0;
float totalCost = 0.0;
float salesTax = 0.0925;

//decalre the functions going to be used
// we don't need to declare main() because it's built-in


//------FUNCTIONS
void addToTotal (float cost, int quantity);
float costWithSalesTax (float price);

//------MAIN PROGRAM


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

   @autoreleasepool {

      float budget = 10000.00;

      // make a new line
      printf("\n");

      //set the price for each item
      float laptopPrice = 1799.00;
      float monitorPrice = 499.80;
      float phonePrice = 199.00;

      addToTotal(laptopPrice, 2);
      addToTotal(monitorPrice, 1);
      addToTotal(phonePrice, 4);

      //display a line then the final total

      printf("----------------------\n");
      printf("TOTAL for %i items: $%5.2f\n\n", totalItems, totalCost);

      if(totalCost < budget)
      {
         printf("You came in under your budget!");
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Your're over your budget. Time to talk to finance.\n\n");
      }
   }

// There's an error in here asking me to put ; after this method declaration.
   void addToTotal (float cost, int quantity)
   {

      printf(" Adding %i items of the cost $%5.2f\n", quantity, cost);

      // find the cost for this item by multiple costs by quantity.
      // and get the real costs by applying sales tax.
      float calculatedCost = cost * quantity;
      float realCost = costWithSalesTax(calculatedCost);

      // and this amount to the total, and increase the total number
      // of items purchased

      totalCost = totalCost + realCost;
      totalItems = totalItems + quantity;

      printf("Subtotal for %i items: $%5.2f\n", totalItems, totalCost);
   }
   // There's an error in here asking me to put ; after this method declaration.
   float costWithSalesTax (float price)
   {
      // remember sales tax is a global variable

      float taxAmount = price * salesTax;
      float subTotal = price + taxAmount;

      return subTotal;

   }

   }
    return 0;  // also this has the error "expected identifier or (" error
}
```

Comment: Objective-C requires that you declare a C-style method before you define it.  Just duplicate your method header with a `;` after the first copy and it will be happy.

Comment: @HotLicks: He already predeclares the C functions. And that's actually an optional compiler warning, not a language requirement.

Comment: You are correct -- I did not look at the code closely enough.  (But whether the lack of a pre-definition produces a warning or an error depends on a compiler setting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to implement your `addToTotal()` and `costWithSalesTax()` functions *inside* of the implementation of `main()`. Move them below the closing `}` instead.

You also have an extra `}` at the end of your code. Specifically, the one before the `return 0;`. Remove it.

Comment: Awesome thanks Kevin.  I thought  I was putting those other methods in the wrong spot.

Comment: @GerardGrundy: Out of curiosity, why are you compiling this as obj-c? The only obj-c in this source is the `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` and the `@autoreleasepool { ... }`. Besides that, what you have here is pure C.

Comment: I'm doing some exercises out of a book called cocoa and Objective C up and running. It's one of the first exercises and I'm just refreshing my mind of how this code works.  I have done a course in Java and now trying to move it over to the Xcode compiler and get it to run in there as I'm more familiar with eclipse.